# Handling Drive Api for Android Callbacks with screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-drive-android-api

After reading many SO threads and answers about proper Activity-Fragment implementation for long running tasks, I currently have an activity adding a UI less Fragment to it thru a FragmentTransaction and letting it run on its own retaining its instance state.

But the problem seems to start off when the "**Google Drive Android API**" object's **Connect method is called (thereby causing a onConnected call)** and **then the activity going thru a restart** due to screen rotation or so.

Now, having a fragment handling the drive mechanism, it causes the fragment to work properly, but many of the drive api calls require a CONTEXT (in the form of activity) to tie back to.

As a result, at a given fraction of time, when the activity is being restarted and fragment is being detached and reattached, there is no guarantee that the getActivity() call would return a correct activity context.

The drive api (inside the onConnected or within some other result callbacks) thereby fail, as they don't have an activity to tie back to.

How to handle such a scenario? Is there a way to tell the drive api to wait while the activity is being recreated?

I can post my code, if that helps, but think this is a pretty generic scenario in handling screen rotations when using drive api for android.

Comment: I'd turn off activity recreation on rotation.  Unless you have separate UIs for landscape and portrait it makes things more complicated, not less.  Even if you do it tends to be less effort if you have anything occurring asynchronously.

Comment: I was connecting / disconnecting using the lifespan of retained fragment, switching activity context new one came/went (onDetach/onAttach).  But I don't remember ever using activity context in any of GDAA calls. Nudge me, please

Comment: @seanpj - But the calls to startResolutionForResult require a actual activity reference and not just a context. Also, where are you storing the context within the UI less fragment? As even if I store the fragment context first hand may be in onAttach or so and try and use that, still because some of the drive api calls require an actual activity, so I end up, getting a failure or so once in a while. Could you please provide some of your google drive api code, so that I can see, if doing something that helps.

Comment: @omkar.ghaisas I was fighting GDAA for only a brief period before I gave up and rolled back to RESTful API (see AndyScan on GooPlay). But I still maintain CRUD (without delete) implementation of GDAA access on GitHub (https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo). If you look at 'GooDrive.java' you'll see the context only in 'init()' to build the client and add callbacks. Other CRUD calls do not need it anymore. The other part of your question about activity in retained fragment, there is method getActivity(), or you may store what you get in onAttach().

Comment: It is possible that we use GDAA for very different purposes and what you see in that GitHub sample is miles away from what you need to accomplish.

Comment: And I just recalled that when using getActivity() in retained frag, I was getting 'null' sometimes. But I guess it is no different from invalidating your copy when you get on onDetach() and saving a new one when you get onAttach().

Comment: "where are you storing the context within the UI less fragment?"
Man, you've just made me to pull the code I hoped I'd never see again. 
see: https://gist.github.com/seanpjanson/1df762153158e021fe0d

Comment: Still no luck on implementing a perfectly working GDAA stuff in the app. Started to use the EventBus methodology now, but haven't finished yet to know for sure, that it does resolve the screen rotation issue when an earlier drive api call is ongoing. Does anyone have a working sample of handling screen rotation with drive android api implementation? The startResolutionForResult which requires a tie back to activity instance, seems to be making things difficult, as you cannot lend the task of handling this whole process to a retained fragment instance, but have to handle it inside activity.